# Conditionally enabling/disabling a @Html.DropDownListFor based on the state of a client-side variable

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net-mvc

I have a dropdownlist like so -

```
    <tr>
       <td>@Html.Label("Data Set")
        </td>

        <td>               
       @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.SelectedID,tDataSetNames,new{id="DataSetDDL"})
        </td>
    </tr>
```

Now "tDataSetNames" is a List which is evaluated at the top of this page using a server side method

```
@{
    List<SelectListItem> tDataSetNames=RDMUtility.GetDataSets();
 }
```

This drop down has to be conditionally enabled or disabled based on the value of a client-side (javascript variable) on this page.

How can this be achieved ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this:

I put a `checkbox` if checked disable select element else enable

```js
$("#myCheckbox").on("change", function (){
  if ($("#myCheckbox").is(":checked"))
      $("#DataSetDDL").prop("disabled", true);
  else
      $("#DataSetDDL").prop("disabled", false);
    
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="DataSetDDL">
  <option value="">select</option>
  <option value="1">1</ption>
  <option value="2">2</ption>

</select>

<input type="checkbox" id="myCheckbox">disable select
```

Or with less code as suggested by @ Tieson T.:

```
$("#myCheckbox").on("change", function (){
      $("#DataSetDDL").prop("disabled", $(this).is(":checked"));    
})
```

Comment: Could probably trim that down to a one-liner: `$("#DataSetDDL").prop("disabled", $(this).is(":checked"));`

Comment: @TiesonT. exactly better approach

Comment: Thank you - I was using the .attr("disabled","disabled") call and was running into issues on that front too. This fixes it !